# Some HTML Tags not working in Cordova application

Tags: html, cordova

We are using CKEditor to add content in HTML format into the database. Then we are using this content to display the HTML in a Cordova application. The client has reported that when using italics (em) and unordered lists (ul/li), the text is displayed as normal text within the application. The HTML that is being saved in the database was tested in a normal browser and it works as expected. There seems to be something disabling these tags from working within the app.

Issue present on both iOS and Android.

When checking the HTML right before being displayed in the app (in debug mode), the HTML seems to be the same as in the database. It does not seem to be affected, but the HTML is just being displayed as raw text.

This is the test HTML Code:

> This is normal text
>
> *This is italic text*
>
> - This is bullet point 1
> - This is bullet point 2

I removed the extra enters from the HTML above (but they should be and are in fact properly displayed within the inspect element in the image below).

[This is how the HTML appears in the Inspect element.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxiwA.jpg)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it _all_ html tags, or just some? One thing I can think of off the top of my head is that characters are getting escaped out somewhere along the line.

Comment: Not all HTML tags. Only the ones mentioned within the question were tested. My guess would be that similar tags would not work. CSS does work though (inline to the HTML content)

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: We are only using iOS and Android. Issue is present on both platforms

Comment: Are you using something like bootstrap that may be overriding the styles?

Comment: We're not using bootstrap but maybe Jquery mobile could be the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This probably needs to be looked at in a web inspector. Open up the phonegap app in an emulator and look at the nodes in question using [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) or [Safari's](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) development tools. Some things to look at:

- What characters are there -- are they escaped (e.g., `&lt;` instead of `<`) or the "true" html that was put in the DB?
- What are the styles being applied? Are there specific rules for `<li>` and `<ul>` that might be causing problems, like a [list-style set to none](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style)?

I should add: Cordova just uses a webview, so there isn't anything wacky about how things display *in and of itself*. My guess is that it's one of those two issues (either corrupted chars or some stylesheet override along the way).

Comment: I tried the Ripple emulator and used the Inspect element. I have updated the question with the raw HTML and the HTML as it appears in the Inspect element.

Comment: Awesome! So it looks like the characters are fine. What are the computed styles for the `<em>` and `<ul>` / `<li>` elements?